# How to find missing number/file ids in a table from given set of dates/month in sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a sequence of file ids which are in the SQL table `file_summary_tbl`.

I want to check if any of the file ids is missing from range start time `20201030` to end time `20201128`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoEKK.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like,

```
SELECT id 
FROM file_summary_tbl tbl1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM file_summary_tbl tbl2
                  WHERE tbl1.id = tbl2.id
                  AND tbl2.date BETWEEN '2020-10-30' AND '2020-11-28')
```

Comment: Thank you for the help ,can you please add one more condition where  file_name like '%rte.rte_ad_order_%' . and the columns of the file_summary_tbl are file_id, processed_file, start_time , end_time and file_name . I need to get data if the file_name like '%rte.rte_ad_order_%' are loaded in sequence and BETWEEN '2020-10-30' AND '2020-11-28'.

Comment: I gave you the basic idea based on the question. It looks like you know where to add them now, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

I think first of all you need to generate the numbers from `20200130` to `20201128` according to dates and then check in your table if the `FILENAME` with this number do exists or not using the `EXISTS` condition as follows:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20201030','YYYYMMDD') + LEVEL - 1,'YYYYMMDD') AS DT
      FROM DUAL CONNECT BY
        TO_DATE('20201030', 'YYYYMMDD') + LEVEL - 1 <= TO_DATE('20201128', 'YYYYMMDD')
)
SELECT DT
  FROM CTE C
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM FILE_SUMMARY_TBL T
     WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(T.FILENAME,'([0-9]+)($|.txt)',1,1,NULL,1) = C.DT);
```